# Reding .dgn v8 file in MapObject2.4 based application

Tags: c#, c, microstation

I have an application which is enabled with **GIS support** provided by **MapObject2.4**. The Application is able to load **.dgn** file v7 using mapobject APIs but its failed to load .dgn v8 file. now i have to provide support of .dgn v8 in my application.  I searched various options in internet but didnt get correct answer what i am looking for.  Currently i am tring to use Microstation SDK to build MDL application that can read .dgn v8 file and conver it in v7 format, so that i will use the output dll in application to convert .dgn v8 to v7 and use that file.
my problem is i dont know mdl programming and even dont know whether can i use mdl compiled dll in my application or not.

Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

MDL generally requires an instance of MicroStation to be running in order to perform any action. Your dll will not be able to run stand alone.

You would be best off posting a question in the [Bentley Developer Network](http://communities.bentley.com/communities/other_communities/bentley_developer_network/default.aspx) (BDN) forum on the Bentley communities site. If you aren't a BDN member apply to become one as you get access to all the SDK's and Bentley's own developers regularly read/post there.

You could also try and look at [Teigha](http://www.opendesign.com/the_oda_platform/Teigha) from Open Design Alliance. They provide libraries for this sort of thing.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to write any code to create a V7 .dgn file.  MicroStation V8 will by default save to its own V8 DGN format, but can also save to a V7 DGN format file.  Just do *File|Save As*.

You can't use MDL in a stand-alone application, by which I mean one that runs independently of MicroStation.